# How to split large xml files into small chunks(Small Xml Files) using StAX In Java

Tags: java, xml, stax

I have **XML** of Having 5 Suppllier's i want split this large file into 2 Suppllier's each the File starting tag is  and ending tag is 
 like this i have 5 Suppllier's...

i red few articles if file size is large go with the ***StaX*** parser my file is ( >6GB ) so how can i split my sample file into multiple files..

Here is my Sample XML File.....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Shop xmlns="http://www.shpAddress.com">
  <tab:Product xmlns:tab="http://www.productName.com">
    <tab:Suppllier>
      <col:Items xmlns:col="http://www.Items.com">
        <col:Delivery>
          <Prize xsi:nil="true" xmlns="" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>              
          <LastModifiedDate xmlns="">2020-01-28</LastModifiedDate>
        </col:Delivery>
      </col:Items>
     </tab:Suppllier>
     <tab:Suppllier>
      <col:Items xmlns:col="http://www.Items.com">
        <col:Delivery>
          <Prize xsi:nil="true" xmlns="" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>          
          <LastModifiedDate xmlns="">2021-02-28</LastModifiedDate>
        </col:Delivery>
      </col:Items>
     </tab:Suppllier>
     <tab:Suppllier>
      <col:Items xmlns:col="http://www.Items.com">
        <col:Delivery>
          <Prize xsi:nil="true" xmlns="" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>          
          <LastModifiedDate xmlns="">2022-02-28</LastModifiedDate>
        </col:Delivery>
      </col:Items>
     </tab:Suppllier>
     <tab:Suppllier>
      <col:Items xmlns:col="http://www.Items.com">
        <col:Delivery>
          <Prize xsi:nil="true" xmlns="" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>          
          <LastModifiedDate xmlns="">2023-03-28</LastModifiedDate>
        </col:Delivery>
      </col:Items>
     </tab:Suppllier>
     <tab:Suppllier>
      <col:Items xmlns:col="http://www.Items.com">
        <col:Delivery>
          <Prize xsi:nil="true" xmlns="" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>          
          <LastModifiedDate xmlns="">2024-04-28+05:30</LastModifiedDate>
        </col:Delivery>
      </col:Items>
     </tab:Suppllier>
  </tab:Product>
</Shop>
```

Comment: Practically speaking, read the file and write to file. Whenever you finish encountering two <tab:supplier> tags, close all remaining tags in the written file and reopen a new file.

Comment: Please show your best efforts so we can see where you got stuck. It's hard to help you without knowing where you hit problems (short of writing the code for you, which few of us have the time to do)

Answer (score 0):

There's expected bunch of boilerplate code with the StaX. It's hopefully possible to restrain it in 2 times with SAXParser/XMLOutputFactory pair.

If a format of XML is quite stable there's another approach looking much simple. Trivial regexp can pick a text between `<tab:Suppllier>` and `</tab:Suppllier>` tags. Other stable parts (at very beginning and ending of XML) can be hard-coded and written to the new partial files.